# How To Navigate From Child Window To User Control Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, prism

I have a child window with two buttons.  When a button click event occurs I need to navigate to a specific user control. How to do this in Prism Framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using PRISM will be simple as fires  a notification event  using the event aggregator. Anyway if not, this will solve your problem.

You need when you fire the childwindow  to add  the close  event to that childwindow, like this:

```
YourChildWindow childWindow = new YourChildWindow (); 

childWindow.Closed += new EventHandler 

(YourChildWindowClosed); 

childWindow.Show();
```

Then,

?

```
void YourChildWindowClosed(object sender, EventArgs e) 

{

YourChildWindow yourChildWindow = ((YourChildWindow)sender); 

if 

(yourChildWindow.DialogResult.Value) 

{

... do your things here ... 

}

}
```

I hope this can help you.